.NET difference in DateTIme parsing
I'm using .NET 8 and I noticed that DateTime strings from requests are parsed differently in the query parameters and in the body.
I have made this example request to show the issue:
POST /api/Save?ValidFrom=2024-01-01T00:00:00+01:00

{
"validFrom":"2024-01-01T00:00:00+01:00"
}

As you can see the date in the query parameters and the body are identical. I'm using the ISO8601 format. The problem is, that now on the controller method the date from the query parameters is parsed as UTC Kind "31.12.2023 23:00:00" and the one from the body as Local Kind "01.01.2024 00:00:00".
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<InstitutionContributionRecognitionModel>> SaveAsync(DateTime ValidFrom, [FromBody] Model model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // ValidFrom = 31.12.2023 23:00:00
    // model.ValidFrom = 01.01.2024 00:00:00
}

Is there a way to use the same parsing behaviour in the query parameters? Only workaround I currently see is to use DateTimeOffset in the query parameter and then use the DateTimeOffset.DateTime to retrieve the client's local date.

"to use DateTimeOffset" - exactly what I would recommend anyway. Apart from requiring inputs to be in UTC, only.

To echo the sentiment, using DateTimeOffset isn't a "workaround" - it's the correct thing to use when these locale differences matter.

I tought that DateTime was using the local representation of the ISO8601 date. I changed the timezone in the browsr only and it looks like it was just the always the utc date, and the local kind was with the server's timezone offset. So it doesn't work without DateTimeOffset anyway, because the real offset is gone.

There really seems to be an issue with how .NET treats parameters differently:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11584
I ended up using a custom model binder:
public class ISO8601DateTimeModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    private class ISO8601DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

            var modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
            var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName);
            if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
            {
                // no entry
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            var modelState = bindingContext.ModelState;
            modelState.SetModelValue(modelName, valueProviderResult);

            var metadata = bindingContext.ModelMetadata;
            var type = metadata.UnderlyingOrModelType;

            var value = valueProviderResult.FirstValue;

            object? model;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            {
                model = null;
            }
            else if (type == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                model = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value).DateTime;
            }
            else
            {
                // unreachable
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            // When converting value, a null model may indicate a failed conversion for an otherwise required
            // model (can't set a ValueType to null). This detects if a null model value is acceptable given the
            // current bindingContext. If not, an error is logged.
            if (model == null && !metadata.IsReferenceOrNullableType)
            {
                modelState.TryAddModelError(modelName, metadata.ModelBindingMessageProvider.ValueMustNotBeNullAccessor(valueProviderResult.ToString()));
            }
            else
            {
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        var modelType = context.Metadata.UnderlyingOrModelType;

        if (modelType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            return new ISO8601DateTimeModelBinder();
        }

        return default!;
    }
}


Use DateTimeOffset so that the timezone information is preserved during parsing. So update your controller method to use DateTimeOffset. Something like this:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<InstitutionContributionRecognitionModel>> SaveAsync(
    DateTimeOffset ValidFrom,
    [FromBody] Model model,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Both ValidFrom and model.ValidFrom should be the same now.
}

Also, update your model to use DateTimeOffset, too.
public class Model
{
    public DateTimeOffset ValidFrom { get; set; }
}


It's the right way to preserve the client's offset with ISO8601 dates and the problem with the different Kind doesn't matter anymore. Doesn't answer though why the DateTime.Kind is different in the query and the body.

Note that the time zone is technically never there and can't be preserved. The offset is what is preserved. This is important when dealing with cross-over times when DST changes occur. The offset will suddenly change (maybe) depending on the time zone. Several time zones can share the same offset during different times of the year.
